# return statement inside conditional statement is giving unexpected results in Python

Tags: python, recursion

For the code below:

```
su = 0
def sod(N):
    global su
    su += N%10
        if N != 0:
            N = int(N/10)
            sod(N)
    return su

print(sod(int(input())))
```

The result is correct. For example., for input 16 its printing 7.

But for the code below

```
su = 0
def sod(N):
    global su
    su += N%10
        if N != 0:
            N = int(N/10)
            sod(N)
        else:
            return su

print(sod(int(input())))
```

The result is unexpected. Its printing **None**.

Comment: You should really by capturing the return value of `sod(N//10)` and summing it with `n%10` instead of using globals.

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that your recursive function does not return anything when `N` is different from zero...